# Help for running commands and install gau.go

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I found in github a url fetcher and i want to try it. I tried to install it with the command `GO111MODULE=on go get -u -v github.com/lc/gau` but it give me unknown command as an error. Can you help me to install it and run the commands. By the way i am on windows 10 and using kali linux subsystem and ubuntu one also.
Thanks! :)

Comment: A fast answer could be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Bruh why there is no answers?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the version of Ubuntu WSL you are using, the steps you took to install gau.go and the command you ran which gave the error. Also, please note this is a community driven Q&A site. All answers are posted voluntarily. So, nobody knows when would you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you installed golang compiler already,

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install golang
```

Then run "GO111MODULE=on" in a separate line

```
GO111MODULE=on
```

Then run the rest of the commands,

```
sudo go get -u -v github.com/lc/gau
```

Finally, use the gau tool, first move to the clone path of the gau tool, on K/Ubuntu is usually `/usr/local/bin/gau/cmd/gau`, eg:

```
cd /[gau_path]/
sudo go run gau example-website.com
```

Comment: `GO111MODULE=on` on a separate line without exporting `GO111MODULE` won't affect `go get...`. And even with exporting, it might not affect it because you're using `sudo`.